# Simplifying a difficult expression to input it in R

Tags: statistics, optimization

The function is $\Large f(X,Y|\mu_1,\mu_1,\theta)=\frac{\phi (X-\mu_1)\phi (Y-\mu_2)\theta(1-e^{-\theta})e^{-\theta (\Phi(X-\mu_1)+\Phi(Y-\mu_2))}}{[1-e^{-\theta}-(1-e^{-\theta \Phi (X-\mu_1)})(1-e^{-\theta \Phi (Y-\mu_2)}]^2}$, where $\theta$ is the pdf and $\Phi$ is the cdf of a standard normal.

I am taking the log likelihood of it so $\large l(\mu_1,\mu_2,\theta|X,Y)=\sum_{n=1}^{50} log[{\phi (X-\mu_1)\phi (Y-\mu_2)\theta(1-e^{-\theta})e^{-\theta (\Phi(X-\mu_1)+\Phi(Y-\mu_2))}}]-2log{[1-e^{-\theta}-(1-e^{-\theta \Phi (X-\mu_1)})(1-e^{-\theta \Phi (Y-\mu_2)}]} $

I am trying to use the Newton-Rhapson algorithm to find the optimal coeffecients, but I dont know how to account for $\Phi$ in R, since it has no closed form and the arguments are variables. Is there a way I can simplify it in wolfram?

Any help would be appreciated